# How to find peaks in List contour plot figure

Tags: plotting, data

```
Mat = {{4, 1125, 4348, 4524, 2906, 1989, 1237, 1524, 1427, 1272, 483, 
82, 19, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 358, 4182, 7850, 5324, 4121, 3061, 2688, 
1293, 1937, 120, 107, 6, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 157, 379, 26, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 108, 173, 117, 36, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 111, 74, 30, 29, 29, 36, 48, 32, 
6, 3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 285, 159, 154, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 89, 139, 83, 16, 12, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
0, 47, 254, 50, 13, 24, 63, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
 3, 47, 170, 95, 84, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 18, 180, 85, 
94, 196, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

x = {1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1, 6/5, 7/5, 8/5, 9/5, 2};

y = {200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 
   850, 900, 950};

data3 = Flatten /@Flatten[Transpose[{Outer[List, x, y], Mat}, {3, 2, 1}], 1];

ListContourPlot[MapAt[Log, data3, {All, ;; 1}], PlotRange -> All,
   Contours -> 10, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], ImageSize -> 400, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ColorFunction -> {"DarkTerrain"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{300, 500, 700, 900, 1000}, 
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, 
       Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}]
```

[image]

I want to plot line through the maxima points in the list contour plot figure

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean - I see just one peak in the figure.  Do you want to draw a line from top to bottom tracing the maximum of each row, or a line from left to right tracing the maximum of each column?

Comment: line show the peaks through contours relative to the value of x axis

Comment: Don't the peaks lie on a contour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a max line going horizontally or vertically.  The point of the obtuse code below is to first find the max value for each row of `Mat`, then find the position of that value in `data4` and extract the first two elements associated with that value.  Then you have to sort so that your line doesn't zigzag.

```
maxVline = 
 Sort[Extract[data4, 
      ReplacePart[Position[data4, Max[#]], {1, 2} -> {1, 2}]][[1]] & /@
    Transpose@Mat, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
maxHline = 
 Sort[Extract[data4, 
      ReplacePart[Position[data4, Max[#]], {1, 2} -> {1, 2}]][[1]] & /@
    Mat, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
(* {{-Log[5], 200}, {-Log[5], 200}, {-Log[5], 250}, {-Log[5], 
  300}, {-Log[5/2], 350}, {-Log[5/2], 400}, {-Log[5/2], 
  450}, {-Log[5/2], 500}, {-Log[5/2], 550}, {-Log[5], 
  600}, {-Log[5/2], 650}, {-Log[5], 700}, {-Log[5/2], 
  750}, {-Log[5/2], 800}, {-Log[5/2], 800}, {0, 800}} *)
(* {{-Log[5], 350}, {-Log[5/2], 350}, {-Log[5/3], 
  350}, {-Log[5/4], 400}, {0, 450}, {Log[6/5], 400}, {Log[7/5], 
  400}, {Log[8/5], 350}, {Log[9/5], 500}, {Log[2], 550}} *)
```

Now you can use `Show` to combine the contour plot with a line plot,

```
ctplot = ListContourPlot[data4, PlotRange -> All, 
   Contours -> 10,(*InterpolationOrder\[Rule]3,*)
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], ImageSize -> 400, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ColorFunction -> {"DarkTerrain"}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{300, 500, 700, 900, 1000}, 
      Charting`Scaled + 
       FrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}];
Show[ctplot, ListLinePlot[maxVline, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}]]
Show[ctplot, 
 ListLinePlot[maxHline, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help! If that solves your problem go ahead and click the checkmark next to the answer so it doesn't show up in the "Unanswered Questions" list (there's also an up arrow there :-)